# How to create a layout with 2 menu bars in css?

Tags: html, css

I have next markup:

```
<div id="lefttop"></div>
<div id="leftbottom"></div>
<div id="central"></div>
```

I need markup as shown on the picture below:
[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/9894/makeupi.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/9894/makeupi.png)

Comment: I think doctype.com (as well as startups.com) was created only in marketing purposes and SO is the best place for this kind of questions. I don't believe that experienced php/ruby/asp.net/java.. developers don't know and don't want to answer questions about html or css.

Comment: what is your question? "please send me the stuff" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#lefttop, #leftbottom {float:left;width:200px;}
#leftbottom {clear:left;}
#central {margin-left:200px;float:right;width: the-width-you-need px}
```

Come to think of it, width:auto might be the best choice for #central

*edit sorry for all the typos earlier

Comment: no, it doesn't work. central panel is under leftbottom panel. even when I set huge margin it still displayed under it's correct place.

Comment: There are a lot of typos in this code, have you fixed those in your test, or have you just copy-pasted everything?

Comment: actually, I don't clearly understand why, but you solution works when I don't set margin-left for #central.

Comment: I think margin-left is not necessary (can't test this at the moment). BTW, you need "float: right" (third line) and a semicolon between "left:width" (first line).

Answer (score 2):

Can you put #lefttop and #leftbottom together in one div? Like

```
<div id="left-container">
    <div id="lefttop"></div>
    <div id="leftbottom"></div>
</div>
```

That way it's easier to get them both on the left.

Answer (score 0):

This may actually work slightly better for you, as all three divs will scale/shift to match the browser window.

```
#lefttop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#leftbottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#central {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 220px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: position: absolute? I would not recommend to do this on this way.